# Removing another JComponent when JComboBox item changed

Tags: java, swing

I want to remove `labell10` and combo box - `level` when I change from programing book item in combo box `category`. I already done similar coding and they are working. But in this case form remain lower parts of `l10` and `level`. I just want to display `JTextField` `agegroup` and change text of `l8` to age group when item art book selected in combo box category. And similarly `l8` must be language and `slanguage` combo box must be display and text field `agegroup` must be removed when category is story book. Also need text field `planguage` and combo box level add if category is programing box. And when we change from one category to another previous displayed items must be removed.

```
public static void add() {
        JFrame f1 = new JFrame();
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Add Book");
        l1.setBounds(10, 10, 400, 25);
        Font f = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 25);
        l1.setFont(f);
        f1.setSize(475, 700);
        f1.setVisible(true);
        f1.setLayout(null);
        f1.add(l1);
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Referance Number:");
        l2.setBounds(10, 45, 300, 25);
        f1.add(l2);
        JTextField RNo = new JTextField();
        RNo.setBounds(130, 45, 200, 25);
        f1.add(RNo);
        JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Title :");
        l3.setBounds(10, 80, 350, 25);
        f1.add(l3);
        JTextField Title = new JTextField();
        Title.setBounds(130, 80, 300, 25);
        f1.add(Title);
        JLabel l4 = new JLabel("Actual unit price:");
        l4.setBounds(10, 115, 100, 25);
        f1.add(l4);
        JTextField AUPrice = new JTextField();
        AUPrice.setBounds(130, 115, 60, 25);
        f1.add(AUPrice);
        JLabel l5 = new JLabel("QTY:");
        l5.setBounds(230, 115, 60, 25);
        f1.add(l5);
        JTextField QTY = new JTextField();
        QTY.setBounds(300, 115, 60, 25);
        f1.add(QTY);
        JLabel l6 = new JLabel("Description:");
        l6.setBounds(10, 150, 100, 25);
        f1.add(l6);
        JTextArea Des = new JTextArea();
        Des.setBounds(130, 185, 300, 200);
        f1.add(Des);
        JLabel l9 = new JLabel("Author:");
        l9.setBounds(10, 395, 100, 25);
        f1.add(l9);
        JTextField Author = new JTextField();
        Author.setBounds(130, 395, 300, 25);
        f1.add(Author);
        JLabel l7 = new JLabel("Category:");
        l7.setBounds(10, 430, 100, 25);
        f1.add(l7);
        JComboBox booktype = new JComboBox();
        booktype.setBounds(130, 430, 200, 25);
        booktype.addItem("Story Book");
        booktype.addItem("Programing Book");
        booktype.addItem("Art Book");
        f1.add(booktype);
        JLabel l8 = new JLabel("language:");
        l8.setBounds(10, 465, 200, 25);
        f1.add(l8);
        JTextField Agegroup = new JTextField();
        Agegroup.setBounds(130, 465, 200, 25);
        JComboBox slanguage = new JComboBox();
        slanguage.addItem("sinhala");
        slanguage.addItem("English");
        slanguage.addItem("Tamil");
        slanguage.setBounds(130, 465, 200, 25);
        f1.add(slanguage);
        JLabel l10 = new JLabel("Type:");
        l10.setBounds(10, 500, 200, 25);
        JComboBox level = new JComboBox();
        level.addItem("Advance");
        level.addItem("Medium");
        level.addItem("Entry");
        level.setBounds(130, 500, 200, 25);
        JTextField planguage = new JTextField();
        planguage.setBounds(130, 465, 200, 25);
        booktype.addItemListener((ItemEvent e) -> {
            if (e.getItem() == "Art Book") {
                f1.remove(slanguage);
                f1.remove(level);
                f1.remove(l10);
                f1.remove(planguage);
                l8.setText("Age group");
                f1.add(Agegroup);

            } else if (e.getItem() == "Programing Book") {
                l8.setText("language:");
                f1.remove(Agegroup);
                f1.remove(slanguage);
                f1.add(l10);
                f1.add(planguage);
                f1.add(level);
            } else {
                f1.remove(Agegroup);
                f1.remove(planguage);
                f1.remove(level);
                f1.remove(l10);
                f1.add(slanguage);
                l8.setText("language:");

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use ..

Comment: .. layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: .. 4) You've described a requirement or specification, but asked no question. What is your question?

Comment: when i changed the category combobox item to storybook from programming the label l10 and level still there. that is my problem

Comment: *"that is my problem"* What is your *question?*

Answer (score -1):

Ans:-added repaint() method

```
public static void add() {
        JFrame f1 = new JFrame();
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Add Book");
        l1.setBounds(10, 10, 400, 25);
        Font f = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 25);
        l1.setFont(f);
        f1.setSize(475, 700);

        f1.setLayout(null);
        f1.add(l1);
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Referance Number:");
        l2.setBounds(10, 45, 300, 25);
        f1.add(l2);
        JTextField RNo = new JTextField();
        RNo.setBounds(130, 45, 200, 25);
        f1.add(RNo);
        JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Title :");
        l3.setBounds(10, 80, 350, 25);
        f1.add(l3);
        JTextField Title = new JTextField();
        Title.setBounds(130, 80, 300, 25);
        f1.add(Title);
        JLabel l4 = new JLabel("Actual unit price:");
        l4.setBounds(10, 115, 100, 25);
        f1.add(l4);
        JTextField AUPrice = new JTextField();
        AUPrice.setBounds(130, 115, 60, 25);
        f1.add(AUPrice);
        JLabel l5 = new JLabel("QTY:");
        l5.setBounds(230, 115, 60, 25);
        f1.add(l5);
        JTextField QTY = new JTextField();
        QTY.setBounds(300, 115, 60, 25);
        f1.add(QTY);
        JLabel l6 = new JLabel("Description:");
        l6.setBounds(10, 150, 100, 25);
        f1.add(l6);
        JTextArea Des = new JTextArea();
        Des.setBounds(130, 185, 300, 200);
        f1.add(Des);
        JLabel l9 = new JLabel("Author:");
        l9.setBounds(10, 395, 100, 25);
        f1.add(l9);
        JTextField Author = new JTextField();
        Author.setBounds(130, 395, 300, 25);
        f1.add(Author);
        JLabel l7 = new JLabel("Category:");
        l7.setBounds(10, 430, 100, 25);
        f1.add(l7);
        JComboBox booktype = new JComboBox();
        booktype.setBounds(130, 430, 200, 25);
        booktype.addItem("Story Book");
        booktype.addItem("Programing Book");
        booktype.addItem("Art Book");
        f1.add(booktype);
        JLabel l8 = new JLabel("language:");
        l8.setBounds(10, 465, 200, 25);
        f1.add(l8);
        JTextField Agegroup = new JTextField();
        Agegroup.setBounds(130, 465, 200, 25);
        JComboBox slanguage = new JComboBox();
        slanguage.addItem("sinhala");
        slanguage.addItem("English");
        slanguage.addItem("Tamil");
        slanguage.setBounds(130, 465, 200, 25);
        f1.add(slanguage);
        JLabel l10 = new JLabel("Type:");
        l10.setBounds(10, 500, 200, 25);
        JComboBox level = new JComboBox();
        level.addItem("Advance");
        level.addItem("Medium");
        level.addItem("Entry");
        level.setBounds(130, 500, 200, 25);
        JTextField planguage = new JTextField();
        planguage.setBounds(130, 465, 200, 25);
        booktype.addItemListener((ItemEvent e) -> {
            if (e.getItem() == "Art Book") {
                f1.remove(slanguage);
                f1.remove(level);
                f1.remove(l10);
                f1.remove(planguage);
                l8.setText("Age group");
                f1.add(Agegroup);
                f1.repaint();
            } else if (e.getItem() == "Programing Book") {
                l8.setText("language:");
                f1.remove(Agegroup);
                f1.remove(slanguage);
                f1.add(l10);
                f1.add(planguage);
                f1.add(level);
                f1.repaint();
            } else {
                f1.remove(Agegroup);
                f1.remove(planguage);
                f1.remove(level);
                f1.remove(l10);
                f1.add(slanguage);
                l8.setText("language:");
                f1.repaint();

            }
        });
        f1.setVisible(true);
    }
```